# Selective UITableView delete cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4, uitableview

I have a picture app with a queue in it. I want the user to be able to delete images from it, but not the one being uploaded. So I have something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//NSString *indexPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath];
NSString *theObject = [processList objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"theObject: %@", theObject);

NSString *theStatus;
NSArray *resultstwoo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM processes WHERE image=?", theObject]; 
for (NSDictionary *rowtwoo in resultstwoo) {
    theStatus = [rowtwoo valueForKey:@"status"];
}

NSLog(@"the status: %@", theStatus);

if ([theStatus isEqualToString:@"Uploading..."]) {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
} else if ([theStatus isEqualToString:@"Resizing..."]) {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
} else {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

}
```

Even though my NSLog says it's "Uploading...", it still shows the delete button.

Please help, thanks:
Coulton!

Comment: After you add the row which is currently uploading, try calling `[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]` and see if the delete button goes away (`indexPathsArray` being a one-element array with the `NSIndexPath` in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
```

let it return NO if it's uploading?